# Retraction and intersection

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space, and consider two open subsets $U$, $V$ of $X$ such that there exist two continuous maps $r_{U}: X\longrightarrow U$, $r_{V}:X\longrightarrow V$ which are homotopically equivalent to retractions. Assuming that $U\cap V\ne \emptyset$, is it possible to constuct a map $r_{U\cap V}: X\longrightarrow U\cap V$ which is homotopically equivalent to a retraction? If not, are there non-trivial additional hypothesis on the choice of $U$ and $V$ which would make things work?

Comment: Not in this generality, for instance $X,U,V$ might be connected while the intersection $U\cap V$ isn't.

Comment: My problem, in its generality, is the following. Given a topological space $X$, I would like to be able to give a simple characterization of all open coverings $\{U_{i}\}$ of $X$ such that for all finite intersections $\cap_{i\in I} U_{i}$ there exist group homomorphisms $f:\pi_{1}(X,p)\rightarrow \pi_{1}(\cap_{i\in I} U_{i}, p)$ such that $f|_{\cap_{i\in I} U_{i}}=\text{id}_{\cap_{i\in I} U_{i}}$, for all $p\in \cap_{i\in I} U_{i}$. Any ideas on how to go with that?

Comment: What is $f|_{\cap_I U_i}$ supposed to represent? Do you mean that, what you call $f$, is actually $f_*^I$ for some continuous map $f^I:X\to\cap_{i\in I}U_i$ (one for each finite set $I$ of indices), which furthermore is a retraction?

Comment: I was not very precise with the notation. Since $U\subseteq X$, then $\pi_{1}(\cap_{i\in I}U_{i}, p)$ is a subgroup of $\pi_{1}(X,p)$. With the notation above I meant $f|_{\pi_{1}(\cap_{i\in I}U_{i}, p)}=\text{id}_{\pi_{1}(\cap_{i\in I}U_{i}, p)}$

Comment: $U\subset X$ doesn't imply that $\pi_1(U)$ is a subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$: the canonical morphism $i_*:\pi_1(U)\to\pi_1(X)$ need not be injective.